# Streamlit Typeerror Plain typing.NoReturn is not valid as type argument

Tags: python, deployment, streamlit

I just installed streamlit library in anaconda prompt. I'm getting this error when I import streamlit. Python version is 3.7.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18288\942006150.py", line 1, in <module>
    import streamlit as st

  File "C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from streamlit.delta_generator import DeltaGenerator as _DeltaGenerator

  File "C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\delta_generator.py", line 168, in <module>
    DataFrameSelectorMixin,

  File "C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\delta_generator.py", line 303, in DeltaGenerator
    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Callable[..., NoReturn]:

  File "C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 755, in __getitem__
    return self.__getitem_inner__(params)

  File "C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 251, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 774, in __getitem_inner__
    result = _type_check(result, msg)

  File "C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 135, in _type_check
    raise TypeError(f"Plain {arg} is not valid as type argument")

TypeError: Plain typing.NoReturn is not valid as type argument
```

Comment: Try [updating](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/introducing-multipage-apps/25986/21) to python >=3.7.2 or install an older version of `streamlit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered in the comments by @RJ Adriaansen:

This is a bug in `python` versions `3.7` and `3.8`.

See this [bug-report](https://bugs.python.org/issue34921)